# ntp v3 authentication using python

Tags: python, ntp

We have implemented SNTP as mentioned in the RFC1769.
Now we want to provide the Authentication mechanism to it, so as mentioned in the RFC1769 we are referring to RFC1305. We are using Coro python to do it.
Any pointers on how to proceed on this?
Any examples on how to set the header?
We may need to write a encrpt/decrpt function too.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a little unclear what the question is. Did you see appendix C in rfc1305?

Comment: The quickest way to grasp what it is would be to build `ntpd` from its source code and watch how they communicate in your lab LAN with `tcpdump`.  You can also modify the source code to insert lots of `printf`'s.

Comment: Hi dfc, I did refer to RFC 1305 but did not understand it properly.Can you please provide some reference to it, pseudo code or any other pointers?  Regarding question: I want to implement Authentication mechanism to confirm the Source Servers (reference servers).

Comment: Hi nodakai, please site the source code and auth mechanism in that. I am pretty novice in the field so please bare.